Is linear logic with the mix rule truth functional?
Linear logic is not truth functional. If one tries, in the style of classical propositional logic, to make a truth table for $A \otimes B$, $A ⅋ B$, $A \& B$, and $A \oplus B$, for $A,B \in \{0,\bot,1,\top\}$, one can use these generic relations to simplify the formulas: $A \otimes 1 = A$, $A \otimes 0 = 0$, $A ⅋ \bot = A$, $A ⅋ \top = \top$, $A \& \top = A$, $A \& 0 = 0$, $A \oplus 0 = A$, $A \oplus \top = \top$. In addition, $\top\otimes\top = \top$ and its dual $0⅋ 0 = 0$ and the generic $A = A \& A = A\oplus A$. Using all this, the "truth table" becomes:



$A$
$B$
$A\otimes B$
$A⅋ B$
$A\&B$
$A\oplus B$




0
0
0
0
0
0


0
$\bot$
0
0
0
$\bot$


0
1
0
$0⅋1$
0
1


0
$\top$
0
$\top$
0
$\top$


$\bot$
$\bot$
$\bot\otimes\bot$
$\bot$
$\bot$
$\bot$


$\bot$
1
$\bot$
1
$\bot\& 1$
$\bot\oplus 1$


$\bot$
$\top$
$\bot\otimes\top$
$\top$
$\bot$
$\top$


1
1
1
$1⅋1$
1
1


1
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
1
$\top$


$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$



Six formulas above cannot be reduced to any of the four basic units. Now consider the mix rule in the version that includes both the binary and nullary form. Then we can identify $u = \bot = 1$! Now the six formulas above can all be reduced to one of the three units $0,u,\top$ and the table becomes:



$A$
$B$
$A\otimes B$
$A⅋ B$
$A\&B$
$A\oplus B$




0
0
0
0
0
0


0
$u$
0
0
0
$u$


0
$\top$
0
$\top$
0
$\top$


$u$
$u$
$u$
$u$
$u$
$u$


$u$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$u$
$\top$


$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$
$\top$



My questions are:
Q1: Does this show that linear logic (MALL, no exponentials) with the addition of the binary and nullary mix rule is a trivalent, truth functional logic? Or is there some additional subtlety that blocks this conclusion?
Q2 (ref. request): It is usually said that linear logic satisfies the Law of the Excluded Middle (LEM) in the sense that $A^{\perp}⅋ A$ is always and rejects it in the sense that $A^{\perp}\oplus A$ is not always provable. But it seems to me that implicit in that perspective is the notion that a) 1 is a form of "truth" and $\bot$ is a form of "falsity", b) "truth" and "falsity" are distinct. With the mix rule, however, the fact that $u = 1 = \bot = u^{\perp}$ is self-dual and also provable, means that there are formulas $A$ for which $A^{\perp} \otimes A$ and $A^{\perp} \& A$ are provable. Has this perspective on LEM been discussed in some text?

Why there are $10$ rows in first table?

There could have been 16 rows, but only 10 are non-redundant since all connectives in the table are symmetric.

I am a bit stumped. If the operations you provided give a truth-functional semantics for $LL_{mix}$, then by definition $\vdash \varphi(A_1,A_2,\dots)$ should be provable in $LL_{mix}$ iff under all assignments of values ${o,u,\top}$ to the proposition variables $A_1,A_2,\dots$, the value of $\varphi(A_1,A_2,\dots)$ is $u$ or $\top$. Since $A^\bot \oplus A$ does evaluate to $u$ or $\top$ under all assignments, I'd therefore expect the sequent $\vdash A^\bot \oplus A$ to be provable. How does one prove this using LL + binary/nullary mix?

@Z.A.K. hmm, I don't see anything in the sequent calculus itself that makes $A^{\perp}\oplus A$ generically provable, i.e. the existence of a formula such that neither $A$ nor $A^{\perp}$ seems consistent with the inference rules. So that points to a negative answer to Q1...? OTOH, if we know that at least one of $A$ and $A^{\perp}$ is always provable, as is the case at least for formulas consisting of only connectives and the four basic units, then one finds in every instance that $A\oplus A^{\perp}$ is provable.

@ErikT: Yes, this means that the answer to Q1 is negative, this is not a truth-functional semantics for $LL_{mix}$ since it's not complete. NB if we know that $\vdash A$ or $\vdash A^\bot$ are provable, then $A \oplus A^\bot$ is provable: this follows from the inference rules of $\oplus$, and is true as stated even in MALL without the mix rule. But you do get that if something evaluates to $u$ or $\top$ in your semantics, then every substitution instance where all variables are replaced by closed $(\oplus,\otimes,&,⅋,0,1,\top,\bot)$-expressions is provable in the system with the mix rule.

Basically, you've found a 3-element algebra in which every theorem of $LL_{mix}$ evaluates to either $u$ or $\top$. But not vice versa: a lot of expressions evaluate to $u$ or $\top$ in your algebra without being theorems of $LL_{mix}$. You could try to set up a sequent proof system mirroring ${u,\top}$ in your algebra (like $LK$ mirrors the set ${1}$ in the 2-element Boolean algebra), but the system for $LL_{mix}$ is not going to be it: you'd need something with rules that allow you to prove e.g. $\vdash A \oplus A^\bot$ and $\vdash (A^\bot ⅋ B) \oplus (B^\bot ⅋ A)$ and lots of others.

@Z.A.K. Thanks for explaining this. By the way, it occurs to me that one can basically copy the standard proof of LEM in classical propositional logic to get close but not all the way: $\vdash A, A^{\perp}$, then $\oplus$-introduction yields $\vdash A, A^{\perp}+A$ and one more time yields $\vdash A+A^{\perp}, A^{\perp}+A$. However, there seems to be no way of using the mix rule to get further.

Q1. If $LL_{mix}$ (MALL + nullary and binary mix rules) was a trivalent, truth functional logic with the operations you provided, then we could find a subset $S \subseteq \{o,u,\top\}$ of your truth values so that $\vdash \varphi(A_1,A_2,\dots)$ is provable in $LL_{mix}$ precisely if under all assignments of truth values $\{o,u,\top\}$ to the propositional variables $A_1,A_2,\dots$, the value of $\varphi(A_1,A_2,\dots)$ belongs to $S$.
There is no such set $S$. Since $\vdash A^\bot ⅋ A$, and the expression $A^\bot ⅋ A$ evaluates to $u$ or $\top$ under every assignment, we must have $\{u,\top\} \subseteq S$.
But the expression $A^\bot \oplus A$ also evaluates to $u$ or $\top$ under every assignments, and we clearly don't have a proof of $\vdash A^\bot \oplus A$ in $LL_{mix}$ (just by considering the possible cut-free proof trees).
Q2. $LL_{mix}$, just like MALL itself, still has LEM in the sense that $A^\bot ⅋ A$ has a proof and lacks LEM in the sense that $A^\bot \oplus A$ does not have a proof. So in this sense, there is no difference. One can regard the equating of $1$ and $\bot$ as a form of paraconsistency. Lots of the literature studies paraconsistency; while it's hard to prove a negative, given how under-studied the nullary mix rule is, I doubt there has been anything specific written about it in the context of $LL_{mix}$ though. Given that nullary mix is incompatible with weakening, and hence with intuitionistic/classical logic, I'd personally look for a more resource-like or game-like and less truth-like interpretation here.

Q1: thanks! Taking this as conclusive.
Q2: I think the classical LEM involves affirming the validity of $A\lor \lnot A$ and $\lnot \lnot A = A$ as well as denying that $A\land \lnot A$. So it's a weird situation now that $\vdash A$, $\vdash A^{\perp}$, $\vdash A& A^{\perp}$ and $\vdash A\otimes A^{\perp}$ simultaneously for some $A$. Paraconsistency was a good lead, maybe the literature has some close-ish analogue of this situation even if it is not exact.

I think $A \wedge \neg A \vdash$ would usually be referred to as the law of noncontradiction in the philosophy literature. Dual-intuitionistic logic is one that's usually said to "admit LEM but not LNC" (while its dual, intuitionistic logic admits LNC but not LEM).
